# Custom iOS dynamic framework: Swift class is imported but can't be initialized

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, frameworks

1. I created a Cocoa touch framework
2. I created a public `TestSDK` swift class in that framework, it has `public func makeSomething()`
3. I created an iOS application
4. I built framework
5. I copied `TestSDK` to app and link `TestSDK.framework`
6. I added `import TestSDK` - no errors
7. I added `let sdk = TestSDK()` and get error:

> Invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type
>   'module'

Comment: Might sound stupid, but have you tried renaming the class? It could uncover some underlying class visibility error, for instance.

Comment: tried - the same issue

Comment: Does the error say anything different though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it.

Framework build target device should be NOT "Generic iOS Device" but simulator or real device

Comment: When running the app, you don't select build target of the framework this app is using, so must be something else I reckon.

Comment: First step is to build frawework. Second - to copy TestSDK to app. Third is to build the app. In answer I mean step 1.

Comment: Ah sorry, for some reason I assumed the app and the framework were in the same workspace. I didn't realise you export and manually link it — in this case you need to watch out for the architectures you're building for.

Comment: Thanks it works! Do you know what it causes? I mean what if I need to run both simulator+device?

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing the same thing and it works fine. Just make sure you explicitly mark the class as `public` — default access control level is `internal` in Swift, e.g. only available inside the module.

Comment: class and func are public